# Finding each page's relative location in a website directory structure using a master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm a rookie web developer creating a site in C#, in VS2005 and using a .master file.

I want to make each page in the site aware of its current location in the directory structure, so I can display the appropriate navigation links on each page.

I wrote the following code in the .master file to look up the directory structure relative to the current page. It works fine on my test server at localhost/mysite, but when I push to the public site at www.example.coom, the code breaks.

I figured out that the problem is with the "int depth = h-2" line. If I change it to h-1, it works on mysite.org. But that's an ugly solution.

```
int nUrlSegments = this.Page.Request.Url.Segments.GetLength(0);

string[] thisPageArray = new string[nUrlSegments];

for (int i = 0; i < nUrlSegments; i++)
    thisPageArray[i] = Page.Request.Url.Segments[i].ToString();

int h = 0;
while (!thisPageArray[h].Contains(".aspx"))
    h++;

int depth = h - 2;

string pathToTop = "";

for (int j = 1; j <= depth; j++)
    pathToTop = pathToTop + "../";

string currentpage = thisPageArray[nUrlSegments-1].ToString();
string currentdir = "";

if (nUrlSegments > 1)
    currentdir = thisPageArray[nUrlSegments - 2].ToString();
```

What's a better way to find each page's place in the directory structure?

Comment: I would recommend to switch to Visual Studio 2010, even Express Edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine from the non-Internet world helped me answer this. For the record, here's the solution I came up with using his advice:

```
string[] urlArray = Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath.Split('/');

int depth = urlArray.Length-2;


string pathToTop = "";

for (int j = 1; j <= depth; j++) pathToTop = pathToTop + "../";


string currentpage = urlArray[depth+1];   

string currentdir = "";
string backdir = "";
string twobackdir = "";

currentdir = urlArray[depth];
if (depth > 1) backdir = urlArray[depth-1];
if (depth > 2) twobackdir = urlArray[depth - 2];
```